# I don't find something similar to drush field-create in Drush 9

Tags: 8, drush

I'm looking for a similar command `drush field-create` with Drush 9, I only find `drush generate field` but when I execut it I don't get nothing, also if I try `drush generate field --help`  I get:

```
Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "command_name".
```

There is any way to get `drush field-create` running with Drush 9?

Thanks.

Comment: Drush 9 has started doing a overhaul of all the command but never complete porting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drush field-create` has not been ported to Drush 9.

You can install Drupal console and use [`drupal generate:plugin:field`](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/en/commands/generate-plugin-field.html) instead.